# Trying to figure out how to model this shape

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface

I'm working on creating 3d text for a custom wordmark that isn't a part of any text library. Getting kind of stuck on how to best make the "M" in it.

[image]

I feel like it should be relatively easy, but I'm getting stuck on how to get those curves in there.

So far I started out with a cube then used loop cuts to make some sections.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would just [follow the shape](https://i.imgur.com/46335fJ.jpg).

Comment: This looks as if you the vertices in the inner part of the bow don't share the same xz-coordinates as the outer ones. It seems easier to me to model the base plane first and extrude it afterwards.

Comment: I would go with the "Trace a logo" option https://www.blendernation.com/tutorials/blender-3d-beginner-tutorial-creating-a-logo/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the Red Marking with the Bezier curve set handles to vector Press <kbd>V</kbd> and trace out the letter like this. With the Blue marking make sub divide verts.

[image]

After tracking with the vector handle. Now select the blue marking (sub divided) and make it free handles (Press <kbd>V</kbd>) and pull it up and with the side handle adjust it.

[image]

**Final result**

[image]

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> convert to Mesh.

Press A to select all and Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill faces

Now select the faces and Press <kbd>E</kbd> Extrude.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As said by Leander you should follow the shape, here is a try:

[image]